# How can I make ring from Gaussian distribution

Tags: python, normalization, normal-distribution

[image]

I saw the formula for making a ring from Gaussian on https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05908.pdf
but it did not work, and I found another formula which makes sphere(ring) from 
normal distribution

[image]

it is maked by using GCN. I used this algorithm to make a ring from a normal distribution but it also did not work.

please help me

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work? We will need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to help you.
Please, provide us with the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example works just fine. Here's the relevant python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create and plot multivariate normal distribution
mean = [0, 0]
cov = [[1,0],[0,1]]
x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 100).T
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x, y, 'x')
plt.axis('equal')

# Generate z    
def g(xy):
    res_z = []
    for z in xy:
        z = np.array(z)
        res_z.append(z / 10 + z / np.linalg.norm(z))
    return res_z
xy = zip(x, y)
res_z = g(xy)

# Plot z
zx, zy = zip(*res_z)
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(zx, zy, 'x')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

and this outputs (if you click and drag the figures to the position shown below):

[image: multivariate gaussian remapped to circle]

Note that when you run the script, your output will be *slightly* different, since `np.random.multivariate_normal` is doing random sampling from the underlying distribution (mean `[0,0]`, identity covariance matrix).

I'm on Anaconda 5.1.0, Python 3.6.

HTH.

Comment: How do you know it was the each z's norm?  I wrote the def g(x):
    return z / 10 + z / np.linalg.norm(z) which is norm of all z. I haven't noticed in the paper that it is norm of each z. Anyway thank you!

Comment: @NEMO double bars around `z`, i.e. `||z||` means norm in mathematical notation. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Notation.

Answer (score -1):

I will provide a simpler but faster version of this algorithm:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], [[1, 0], [0,1]], data_size)
Z = X / 10 + X / np.sqrt(np.square(X).sum(axis=1, keepdims=True))
```

and Z is the result you want.